# Resource Graph Query: Get Subscription Name of 2 Subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-resource-graph

I have a ResouceGraph Query like this:

```
RecoveryServicesResources
| where (properties.startTime >= ago(7d))
| extend endTime = todatetime(properties.endTime)
| extend backupInstanceId = tolower(tostring(properties.backupInstanceId))
| extend dataSourceId = tolower(tostring(properties.dataSourceId))
| extend dataSourceSubscriptionId = extract("/subscriptions/(.*?)/", 1, dataSourceId)
| summarize arg_max(endTime, *) by backupInstanceId
| project backupInstanceId, subscriptionId, dataSourceSubscriptionId
```

which give me a table like this back

| ID | subscriptionId | dataSourceSubscriptionId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | 8749684f-50da-4acb-a8dd-203f3d23e4bf | 878c7009-b12e-4b79-b1bf-572b03cf4d61 |
| ID | 8749684f-50da-4acb-a8dd-203f3d23e4bf | a1aa6c3a-0571-4c78-bf4d-437cc8c2adfd |

How to get the Subscription Name of subscriptionId and dataSourceSubscriptionId ?

```
RecoveryServicesResources
| where (properties.startTime >= ago(7d))
| extend endTime = todatetime(properties.endTime)
| extend backupInstanceId = tolower(tostring(properties.backupInstanceId))
| extend dataSourceId = tolower(tostring(properties.dataSourceId))
| extend dataSourceSubscriptionId = extract("/subscriptions/(.*?)/", 1, dataSourceId)
| summarize arg_max(endTime, *) by backupInstanceId
| join kind=inner (
    resourcecontainers
    | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
    | project subscriptionId, subscriptionName = name
    )
    on subscriptionId
| join kind=leftouter (
    resourcecontainers
    | where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
    | project dataSourceSubscriptionId=subscriptionId, dataSourceSubscriptionName = name
    )
    on dataSourceSubscriptionId
| project backupInstanceId, subscriptionId, dataSourceSubscriptionId, subscriptionName, dataSourceSubscriptionName
```

Which give me the error:

> Table resourcecontainers was referenced as right table 2 times, which exceeded the limit of 1. Please see https://aka.ms/resourcegraph-tables for help. (Code:DisallowedMaxNumberOfRemoteTables)?

**NOTE: Any solution which requires a shell wrapper is not acceptable. I have to integrate the query in a 3rd party tool.**

Comment: Remove the `leftouter join` in the above kql query and can you add `subscriptionName` in project statement to pull the subscription Name.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda Thanks and how I get the `subscriptionName` of `subscriptionId` and `dataSourceSubscriptionId`?

Comment: Inner join with `resources` to get the subscription name for subscription id is not required. You can get the subscription name , when you click the formatted result in Query output window. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/YdlsLHo.png). Use only one join to get the subscription name of `dataSourceSubscriptionId`.

Answer (score 0):

> Table resourcecontainers was referenced as right table 2 times, which exceeded the limit of 1. Please see  https://aka.ms/resourcegraph-tables  for help. (Code:DisallowedMaxNumberOfRemoteTables)

This error indicates that `RecoveryServicesResources` is not allowed to join with  `resourcecontainers`  twice. Check the link in the error message. It shows  `resourcecontainers`  supports join partially only. This is the reason for the error.

It is not necessary to join with  `resourcecontainers`  to get the subscription name of subscription id. When  **Formatted result**  is toggled on in the output window, it displays the name of the subscription id. Thus, it is enough to join with  `resourcecontainers`  once only to get the name of  `datasourcesubscriptionId`.

```
RecoveryServicesResources
| where (properties.startTime >= ago(7d))
| extend endTime = todatetime(properties.endTime)
| extend backupInstanceId = tolower(tostring(properties.backupInstanceId))
| extend dataSourceId = tolower(tostring(properties.dataSourceId))
| extend dataSourceSubscriptionId = extract("/subscriptions/(.*?)/", 1, dataSourceId)
| summarize arg_max(endTime, *) by backupInstanceId
| join kind=leftouter (
resourcecontainers
| where type == 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'
| project dataSourceSubscriptionId=subscriptionId, dataSourceSubscriptionName = name
)
on dataSourceSubscriptionId
| project backupInstanceId, subscriptionId, dataSourceSubscriptionId, dataSourceSubscriptionName
```

[image: img1]

Comment: Thanks, but this does only work inside Azure Portal, I have to integrate the query in a 3rd party tool (as mention at the post)

Comment: What is the 3rd party tool you use to integrate the query?